# html - css width applied to div not working

Tags: html, css, width

I have a `div` with class `widget` and I applied `width` and `length` styling to my widget class, but for some reason, the width is still 100% of the screen instead of 200px like I defined below. Can someone help?

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ps17t1a5/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table
}


.widget {

    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 7px;

}

    <body ng-controller="main_controller">
        <div class="widget">
            <h1>{[city]}, {[state]}</h1>
            <div>
                <h1 style="float: left">{[current_temp | degree]}</h1> <h1 style="float: right">afasf</h1>
            </div>
            <p>{[today_day]}</p>
            <p>{[today_high | degree]} / {[today_low | degree]}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: A snippet or a fiddle would help to see the problem in action. `.widget` is a common class, and may be used by a plugin, which overwrites the rule.

Comment: Try removing `display:table` from the `html, body` selector.

Comment: i added a fiddle @IlpoOksanen

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work; i added a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ps17t1a5/ @mikehomme

Comment: if you remove `display: table` from the `body`, the width attribute is honoured.  I am off to try to find out why that is the case (see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ps17t1a5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`Cells` inside a `table` should add up to `100%` of the `table` dimensions. You've set your table to be the `body` element with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` - your `.widget` is the only `cell` and thus makes use of the entire space as a consequence. Simply remove the `display: table` and `display:table-cell` rules, and the dimension rules will work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/ps17t1a5/3/

I don't know why you'd want to use `display:table-cell` in the first place, but I presume it's for vertical and horizontal centering. Should that be the case, use this instead:

```
position: absolute; //or relative or fixed depending on your needs
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Sorry - that was a bad copy and paste. My code already has the 'px' units

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 200px instead of just 200.

Comment: Sorry - that was a bad copy and paste. My code already has the 'px' units

Answer (score 0):

Height and width defined incorrectly, they should be 500px and 200px

Comment: Sorry - that was a bad copy and paste. My code already has the 'px' units

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `display: table` from the `body` makes the `width` attribute be honoured by the rendered element.

Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), it states that this makes the `div` behave like a `table` element.

In this case, it looks like the `table` would contain only one `cell` and, since the same `body` element has an attribute of `width:100%` this makes the `widget` element to have a full width of the cell (hence the full width of the table, hence the full width of the page)

Does that make sense?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*display: table;*/
}
.widget {
  /* added to show box boundaries */
  border: 1px solid green;  
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  width: 310px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<body ng-controller="main_controller">
  <div class="widget">
    <h1>juno, alaska</h1>
    <div>
      <h1 style="float: left">10</h1> 
      <h1 style="float: right">cool</h1>
    </div>
    <p>today</p>
    <p>69/ 88</p>
  </div>
</body>
```